# Issue capturing a bitmap using window handle in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-8, user32

This is my code which works completely fine on windows 7:

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, uint nFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);

        public static Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr hWnd) {
            Rectangle rctForm = Rectangle.Empty;

            using (Graphics grfx = Graphics.FromHdc(DLLImport.GetWindowDC(hWnd))) {
                rctForm = Rectangle.Round(grfx.VisibleClipBounds);
            }

            Bitmap pImage = new Bitmap(rctForm.Width, rctForm.Height);
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pImage);
            IntPtr hDC = graphics.GetHdc();

            try {
                DLLImport.PrintWindow(hWnd, hDC, (uint)0);
            } finally {
                graphics.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
            }

            return pImage;
        }
```

The issue I'm having is that on Windows 8 it appears to generate a completely blank Bitmap (the dimensions are correct though). Does anyone know what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

For the heck of it I'd try passing PW_PRINTCLIENT and see if you get different results, as the target window handles that differently.  However:

Remember that this API isn't magic (I will point you at the magic ones later).  It doesn't grab a window's content really, it grabs visible content with WM_PRINT and some magic:

*"The application that owns the window referenced by hWnd processes the PrintWindow call and renders the image in the device context that is referenced by hdcBlt. The application receives a WM_PRINT message or, if the PW_PRINTCLIENT flag is specified, a WM_PRINTCLIENT message. For more information, see WM_PRINT and WM_PRINTCLIENT."*

You can confirm the "non-magical" part by putting that beautiful, elegant app called "Windows 7 Task Manager" (I'm not on 8 yet) partially obscuring a window, setting to "Always On Top", doing an ALT-PRTSCRN, and seeing that Task Manager is still on top of your window in the screen grab.

In other words, it's ultimately dependent on the app complying and behaving properly to a certain extent.  That's why in the past I've done the "grab the whole screen and blt out the part I want" approach instead.

I don't see anything to indicate that it's different on Windows 8, but if you are Vista or later there is a Desktop Window Manager API that allows you grab an app window (I'd imagine that's how the task bar thumbnails are created).  You can see source code here, and I think it'd be the most reliable way to go:

https://code.google.com/p/zscreen/source/browse/trunk/ZScreenLib/Global/Capture.cs?r=1523

If you need to work pre-Vista, you might wind up with two codepaths, I guess.

If you're strictly Windows 8 or later, there is the "Desktop Duplication API" that might be handy for you.

Comment: All of the proposed solutions are subject to the window display affinity setting, see [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375340.aspx).